# Lambda function sometimes returns a null value for data when calling stripe api

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, stripe-payments

I get the following error occasionaly from my lambda function

```
{
    "errorType": "TypeError",
    "errorMessage": "Cannot read property 'data' of null",
    "stack": [
        "TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null",
        "    at /var/task/app.js:86:21",
        "    at Timeout._onTimeout (/var/task/node_modules/stripe/lib/utils.js:324:13)",
        "    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)",
        "    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)"
    ]
}
```

I am wondering if in my code there is a way if the stripe call is failing (which I think is what is happening) then I can retry , otherwise not sure what to do. Here is my code

```
// const axios = require('axios')
// const url = 'http://checkip.amazonaws.com/';

const sanityClient = require("@sanity/client");
const client = sanityClient({
  projectId: "fdsa...",
  dataset: "development",
  token: process.env.SANITY_TOKEN_WRITE,
});
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const stripe = require("stripe")(`${process.env.STRIPE}`);

let response;

/**
 *
 * Event doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-input-format
 * @param {Object} event - API Gateway Lambda Proxy Input Format
 *
 * Context doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-context.html
 * @param {Object} context
 *
 * Return doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html
 * @returns {Object} object - API Gateway Lambda Proxy Output Format
 *
 */
exports.lambdaHandler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  if (event.httpMethod === "POST") {
    response = {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify({
        message: "hello world",
        // location: ret.data.trim()
      }),
    };

    //console.log(event.body);

    const payload = JSON.parse(event.body);

    async function retrieveProduct() {
      const product = await stripe.checkout.sessions.listLineItems(
        payload.data.object.id,
        { limit: 5 },
        function (err, lineItems) {
          console.log(lineItems);

          let query;
          lineItems.data.map((item) => {
            //console.log(item);

            //console.log(item.id);

            query = `*[_type == "products" && product_id == "${item.price.product}"]`;
            //console.log(query);

            client.fetch(query, {}).then((documents) => {
              //console.log("document");
              //console.log(documents);
              //console.log(documents[0]._id);
              //console.log("document");
              documents.forEach((document) => {
                client
                  .patch(document._id) // Document ID to patch
                  .set({ sold: true }) // Shallow merge
                  .commit()
                  .then((result) => {
                    // console.log(result);
                  });
              });
            });
          });
        }
      );
    }

    async function purchaseRecord() {
      const product = await stripe.checkout.sessions.listLineItems(
        payload.data.object.id,
        { limit: 5 },
        function (err, lineItems) {
          //console.log(lineItems);

          let arr = [];

          lineItems.data.map((item, i) => {
            arr.push({
              _type: "line_items",
              _key: `f83nf893n${i}`,
              line_items: item.price.product,
              line_items_desc: item.description,
            });
            //console.log(item);
          });

          console.log(arr);

          const doc = {
            _type: "purchases",
            cs_id: payload.data.object.id,
            customer_id: payload.data.object.customer,
            amount_total: payload.data.object.amount_total,
            line_items_wrapper: arr,
          };

          client.create(doc).then((res) => {
            console.log(`Purchase was created, document ID is ${res._id}`);
          });
        }
      );
    }

    purchaseRecord();

    retrieveProduct();
  }

  if (event.httpMethod === "GET") {
    try {
      // const ret = await axios(url);
      response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({
          message: "hello world",
          // location: ret.data.trim()
        }),
      };
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return err;
    }
  }

  callback(null, response);
};
```

The code runs like 90% of the time, but this error happens occasionally.

Thanks ahead of time

Answer (score 1):

Change if block with this and you can get error message instead null

```
  if (event.httpMethod === "GET") {
    try {
      // const ret = await axios(url);
      response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({
          message: "hello world",
          // location: ret.data.trim()
        }),
      };
      callback(null, response);

    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      callback(Error(err));

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this has anything to do with the GET request.

I'm not sure where line 86 is, but I think that sometimes `const payload = JSON.parse(event.body);` is empty, so you should check if that actually contains a `data` field before you proceed trying to process it.

Comment: correct the error is happening in the  post request. I will try this and come back and choose this answer. Thanks